# JQuery not loading in nodejs script execution

Tags: jquery, node.js

When I am loading jQuery on the REPL mode of nodejs, it works fine like this:

```
var $ = require('jquery');
```

When I have exact same line in a script and I try to run this from the command line I get this:

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs>node C:\work\script.js

module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'jquery'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\work\script.js:1:71)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
```

I am on Win7 (64 bit) with nodejs v0.10.8.

Comment: Did you run the REPL from the same directory as your command line above? Try `cd \work; node script.js`.

Comment: I have tried running this from the home of the nodejs executable and from the home of the script. No effect.

Comment: Have you installed jquery locally or globally? If local go to that folder and run from there.

Comment: I have installed it like this `npm install -g jquery`. Also any other modules I have installed are loading (e.g. mysql)

Comment: I don't really know the file structure of your project, but this [tutorial from nodetuts](http://nodetuts.com/05-modules.html) explains how modules can be required.